# Как отследить ботов поисковых систем

Tags: seo, php, cookie

Собственно сабж

На сайте есть "всплыхивающая" форма подписки пользователей, которую я показываю в (связи с описанной ниже ситуацией) при втором заходе пользователя (отсеиваю через куки)
Поисковые системы видимо их каждый раз чистят и на каждой проиндексированной странице была эта форма, когда у меня она показывалась при первом заходе пользователя.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поисковых ботов отследить, поймать?
Может дополнительно пользователей проверять на куки других сайтов (например Вконтакте), что-бы понять что это не бот ПС?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$bot_list = array
(
    'Googlebot' => 'Корпорация добра'
    //и т.д. список ботов уже сами допишите
);

foreach($bot_list as $bot_name => $search_engine)
{
    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot_name))
    {
        echo $search_engine;
        //Тут выполняем свои действия с отловленным ботом
    }
}
```

Comment: //Тут выполняем свои действия с отловленным ботом
тут поставил ключ для условия. 
после апдейтов буду смотреть. Спасибо

  'Googlebot' => 'Google',
  'Aport' => 'Aport robot',
  'Google' => 'Google',
  'msnbot' => 'MSN',
  'Rambler' => 'Rambler',
  'Yahoo' => 'Yahoo',
  'IDBot' => 'ID-Search Bot',
  'eStyle' => 'eStyle Bot',
  'Mail.Ru' => 'Mail.Ru Bot',
  'Scrubby' => 'Scrubby robot',
  'Yandex' => 'Yandex',
  'YaDirectBot' => 'Yandex Direct'

вот небольшой список ботов